# How to add a derived class from AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer in Toolbox?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli, clr, axwindowsmediaplayer

This is a CLR Project (.NET Framework 4.5).

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.8.1

Since `AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer` inherits from `System::Windows::Forms::AxHost` and `AxHost` inherits from `System::Windows::Forms::Control`, why `Toolbox` does not support it when adding from `ClassLibrary1.dll`? Instead I got an error: **There are no components in ClassLibrary1.dll that can be placed on the toolbox.**

This is my `ClassLibrary1.dll`:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    public ref class Class1 : public AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer
    {
    public:
        Class1() {}
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [[ToolboxItem(true)]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.toolboxitemattribute?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to your class, for example:

```
[System::ComponentModel::ToolboxItem(true)]
public ref class MyMediaPlayer : public AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: In addition to this answer it's important to note that a default constructor is necessary if you have more constructors, so you must explicitly declare a default constructor otherwise `Toolbox` won't accept it, also both class and its default constructor must have public access modifiers.

Comment: I found a bug on Visual Studio Community 2019 or maybe regardless of any version, maybe you can help me with that. When adding a custom control derived from `AxWMPLib::AxWindowsMediaPlayer` in the Designer, so if you switch the Language of the form in the Designer so the Designer gets all blank and you are forced to close the Designer. Do you know what's that? For other custom controls like derived from System::Windows::Forms* that doesn't happen.